# Is there any way to make these span elements vertically align?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm using a JQuery Sortable control with spans, and I now am having trouble getting elements to vertically align.  Normally, using Div's, I'd just add padding.  In this case though the image is centered but the text is too low and needs to be bumped up a few pixels.

```
            @foreach(var c in companies)
            {
                var company = c.Company;
                <li class="ui-state-default">
                    <span>
                    <img src="..\..\Content\img\udarrow.png"/>
                    </span>
                    <span>
                    @company
                    </span>
                </li>
            }
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You do not need to use span in order to use sortable. In fact, you dont even need to use li. It is semantically correct (since you are probably sorting a list of things) but not necessary. see http://jsfiddle.net/4eHuy/

Comment: Ok, I will look into this and keep it in mind, and I'll correct my post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS:

```
.ui-state-default span {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but it seems to not work in my case.  The elements become stacked, and if I use float:left; width: 100px, the Sortable control goes haywire.  Sorry, I guess this also is a Sortable control problem.

Comment: `float: left;` will make the elements float with each other, even if they're set to `block`. Can you have a screenshot on what you need the output to be?

Comment: Well, it was pretty ugly, but I got it to work when I put the text in a float, but left the image alone.  For some reason it's ok with that.  It's all working great now.

Comment: Heh. Well congrats with that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try converting your spans to block elements.

```
.ui-state-default span { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rather make them `inline-block` than just `block` if they must lay inline with one another. Then just fiddle with the margins & padding.

Comment: inline block results in the same problem as block.  I guess I should have mentioned the Sortable control is interfering with what I'd like to do.